# Apache HTTP server has stopped working while using cakephp code

Tags: apache, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

whenever I click on add button it displays the following error message ie. Apache Http server has stopped working

Table name is matters_task_categories

In view folder I have created Matters folder in that task_categories.ctp file I wrote the code.

There are two categories for two section. For 2 categories there is two different tables for 2 different section.

When I remove code from add page then it works properly.

Comment: Can anyone suggest where I went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the table name maybe there are a conflit with a MAMP table or something like this , try to rename your table like (matter_tasking_categories) and so change the model and controller and views name see the convention name also to follow the right convention to rename cakes class, table and fils.
hope this can help you thanks :)